# Which is write efficient "create table with option With compact storage" or "create table with option With clustering order storage"?

Tags: cassandra, cql3

I am designing schema for a read as as well Write critical Problem statement.
Which will be more write and read efficient Create table with compact storage or create table with the Clustering order.

As per my requirement Clustering order helps me to safe some time during reading. but at the same time i fear that it could effect the insertion.

can any one tell ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compact storage is for backwards compatibility with thrift apps..I'd recommend avoiding it. From the official docs:

> Using compact storage¶
>
> The compact storage directive is used for backward compatibility of
>   old applications with CQL. Use the directive to store data in the
>   legacy (Thrift) storage engine format. To take advantage of CQL
>   capabilities, do not use this directive in new applications.
>
> CREATE TABLE sblocks (   block_id uuid,   subblock_id uuid,   data
>   blob,   PRIMARY KEY (block_id, subblock_id) ) WITH COMPACT STORAGE;
>   Using the compact storage directive prevents you from defining more
>   than one column that is not part of a compound primary key. A compact
>   table using a primary key that is not compound can have multiple
>   columns that are not part of the primary key.
>
> A compact table that uses a compound primary key must define at least
>   one clustering column. Columns cannot be added nor removed after
>   creation of a compact table. Unless you specify WITH COMPACT STORAGE,
>   CQL creates a table with non-compact storage.¶

Comment: so what about clustering order storage. I guess it keeps the the cluster key in sorted order. which will take some time during insertion. is it something related to ordered partitioning?

Comment: Cassandra will keep all rows for a partition in sorted order according to clustering indiced. e.g. if your primary key is (a, b, c, d), then a is the partition key and in that partition, data will be sorted by b, and those with the same (a, b) will be sorted by c...and so on. Remember CUD operations go to the commit log and memtable. They don't hit disk. As such, ingestion (write speed) is very fast. During compaction is when older data is discarded and newer data retained. As such, you don't need to worry much about the sortedness for perf.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I understand by your reply Cassandra store data in the Memtable in the order of insertion. and when data get flushed the data get Aligned in sstable as per order. So when i am writing create table () with Clustering Order(desc) . I don't care about sorting overhead during insertion. please correct  me if am wrong.:)

Comment: Nearly right...SStables are immutable. During compaction, new tables are created, rather than existing ones being mutated. That's going into details, but the point is that insertion goes to commit log and memtable, and as such, you shouldn't worry about the cost of sorting data in files.

Comment: You do need to select your clustering keys and the partition key to be able to perform your queries efficiently while making use of your cluster (i.e. avoiding hotspots in large clusters). That's what you should focus on.

Comment: lets us suppose I have a cluster key name  "A" and i want it to display the data in descending order. do i Need to create table in descending order by using **CLUSTERING ORDER BY(A desc)**. or it will be better to create a simple table and use **order by A desc**

Comment: For ascending, simply having it as the cluster key is enough. For data sorted in descending order on disk, use clustering order by(A desc);. If you're querying in the order that it's stored in, it's a tad faster than if it's the opposite. But even if it's the opposite, performance should still be pretty good. The key is hitting partition keys and clustering keys, and only hitting secondary indexes if absolutely necessary.

Comment: I think i  got the point data is stored in order we defined (as per position of the clustering key by default or we can alter the default behavior by using the CLUSTERING ORDER BY). we can reverse default order or pre-defined order by using orderby

Answer (score 3):

A table with a Clustering order really has no penalty over a table without. Writes always go into the memtable (since Cassandra uses a log structured storage) and is more or less like a line of log. Clustering keys really help while reading to seek to the right CQL row inside a partition. Searching using a Clustering key is very efficient and is really the recommended way to do things.

Comment: so if I  create table by using both clustering order and compact storage together  will that going to bother my read/ write any way.

Comment: With compact storage you lose the ability to have more than one column which is not a part of partition or clustering key. Think of it this way - Cassandra stores stuff as Map<PartitionKey, SortedMap<ClusteringKey,Value>>. Without compact storage in CQL, the ClusteringKey names are repeated for each value. So a CQL row will be multiple entries in the SortedMap. With Compact Storage, the Clustering key names are not repeated. Hence you can have only on value per CQL row. Compact storage is hence not recommended.

Comment: lets us suppose I have a cluster key name "A" and i want it to display the data in descending order. do i Need to create table in descending order by using **CLUSTERING ORDER BY(A desc)**. or it will be better to create a simple table and use **order by A desc**

Comment: I think i  got the point data is stored in order we defined (as per position of the clustering key by default or we can alter the default behavior by using the CLUSTERING ORDER BY). we can reverse default order or pre-defined order by using orderby

Comment: Order by is currently only supported on the clustered columns of the PRIMARY KEY i.e Clustering keys

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the rep for a comment so thought I'd leave this here for anyone who stumbles upon this question and is using C* >= 3.0.

Cassandra's storage engine was re-factored in version 3. Data is now stored more compactly on disk by default. There is no benefit in using the `COMPACT STORAGE` option, besides backwards thrift compatibility, in fact it should be avoided altogether.

[DataStax Reference](http://www.datastax.com/2015/12/storage-engine-30)